# li element jumping out of ul element, position: relative issue

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

[Tristans.tk](http://tristans.tk) 
On this site please look at the pagination links at the bottom. The  li element jumps out of the ul element and I don't want that. This is my PHP script & CSS:

```
$pages=ceil(count(get('SELECT * FROM posts'))/$ipp);
echo "<div class='mid_align' id='pages_div'><ul id='pages_ul'>";
for ($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++) {
    $d=$i-1;
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=$d'>$i</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul></div>";
```

```
.mid_align {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#content #pages_div{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 30px;
}
#content #pages_ul {
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
}
#content #pages_ul li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#content #pages_ul li a{
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Can you 1) post the output of your PHP instead, and 2) make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't **reset** your **CSS** code.

This will work:

```
ul#pages_ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

I advice you to use some [cssreset](http://www.cssreset.com/) in the future.